# Databinding repeater to List<T> - can't find property of T?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, repeater

I have a basic repeater as such:

```
<asp:Repeater id="BlogDisplay" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" align="left" style="font-weight:bold; padding-left:3px;">
                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Title")%>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
```

When I execute the code I get an exception:  `DataBinding:  'DocumentWebParts.BlogPostLost.BlogItem' does not contain a property with the name 'Title'.`

[image: This upsets me]

So you're probably thinking that my BlogItem object doesn't have a `Title` property - but that's not the case!

```
public class BlogItem
{
    public int Id;
    public string Body;
    public string Title;
    public string Author;
    public DateTime Published;
}
```

And the property is certainly being set - throwing a breakpoint shows that all values have been set.

```
BlogItems = new List<BlogItem>();
SPListItem item;
foreach (SPListItem i in myItems)
            {
                //off-topic code hidden

                BlogItem b = new BlogItem();
                b.Id = Id;
                b.Body = Body;
                b.Author = Author;
                b.Title = Title;
                b.Published = Published;
                BlogItems.Add(b);
            }
            BlogItems = BlogItems.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).ToList();
            BlogDisplay.DataSource = BlogItems;
            BlogDisplay.DataBind();
```

So in light of all of this, why am I getting the above exception when I use `DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Title")` in the repeater?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change BlogItem to this:

```
public class BlogItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public DateTime Published { get; set; }
}
```

You are using fields; it expects properties.

Comment: Gawd, I can't believe I missed that.  Thanks.